# Can I earn AI player's votes for a diplomatic victory in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civ 4, as I recall, you could trade for another civilization's vote in the U.N., but I can't seem to find that option in Civ 5.  Are the only votes I can earn those of the city states?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The manual explicitly states that all AI civs will vote for themselves unless they have been liberated.  So the only way to get them to vote for you is to have their capital be captured by another civ, then have you conquer it and give it back to them.

Comment: Because of this, I've heard the diplomatic victory referred to as an "economic victory" because you need to generate enough gold to buy the vote of enough city states.

Comment: Will they also vote for you if its down to you and 1 other civ, whom they've collectively declared eternal war against?

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you're on friendly enough allied terms with an AI, you could get their vote.  There does not seem to be a set-in-stone "I give you my vote" diplomatic agreement, however.

Comment: This only works with city-states, though the OP probably meant other AI *civs*.